# javax.servlet.ServletException: Request[/platform] does not contain handler parameter named 'action'

Tags: struts, struts-1

I work on a Struts software. The software running correctly but when i stay more than 5 minutes doing nothing and that i click to join another page, i get an error 500 :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Request[/platform] does
> not contain handler parameter named 'action'.

I talked with my company and the problem can't be from a server security.

**Web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/GenLicenseDB</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>content</param-name>
      <param-value>utf8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>6</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>convertNull</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>fr.niji.struts.utils.Starter</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list id="WelcomeFileList">
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jws</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**STRUTS-CONFIG.XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <data-sources />

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="platformForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
            <form-property name="action" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="idPlatform" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="platformName" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="idVersion" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="idLicense" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="description" type="java.lang.String" />
        </form-bean>

        <form-bean name="versionForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
            <form-property name="action" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="idVersion" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="compareVersion" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="versionName" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="versionList" type="java.util.List" />
            <form-property name="versionFile" type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile" />
        </form-bean>

        <form-bean name="licenseForm" type="fr.niji.struts.form.LicenseForm" />

        <form-bean name="equipmentsForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
            <form-property name="action" type="java.lang.String" />
            <form-property name="equipmentsList" type="java.util.List" />
            <form-property name="equipmentsFile" type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile" />
        </form-bean>
    </form-beans>



    <global-exceptions>
        <exception key="unauthorized" type="fr.niji.exception.UnauthorizedException"
            path="/login.do" />
    </global-exceptions>

    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="logOff" path="/sessionexpired.do?action=execute" />
        <forward name="MENU_LOGOFF" path="/logout.do" />
    </global-forwards>


    <action-mappings>

        <action path="/UnCaughtFatalErrorAction" type="fr.niji.struts.action.UnCaughtFatalErrorAction">
            <forward name="backToLogin" path="/login.jsp"></forward>
        </action>

        <action path="/sessionexpired" type="fr.niji.struts.action.SessionExpiredAction">
            <forward name="logoff" path="/login.jsp"></forward>
        </action>

        <!-- login action -->
        <action attribute="loginForm" input="/form/login.jsp" name="loginForm"
            path="/login" scope="request" type="fr.niji.struts.action.LoginAction">
            <forward name="login_ko" path="/login.jsp" />
            <forward name="login_ok" path="/imput.do?action=init" />
        </action>

        <action attribute="platformForm" name="platformForm" path="/platform"
            scope="request" parameter="action" type="fr.niji.struts.action.PlatformAction">

            <forward name="list" path="/listPlatforms.jsp" />
            <forward name="display" path="/displayPlatform.jsp" />
            <forward name="change" path="/displayPlatform.jsp" />
        </action>

        <action attribute="versionForm" name="versionForm" path="/version"
            scope="request" parameter="action" type="fr.niji.struts.action.VersionAction">

            <forward name="list" path="/listVersions.jsp" />
            <forward name="display" path="/displayVersion.jsp" />
            <forward name="add" path="/addVersion.jsp" />
        </action>

        <action attribute="licenseForm" name="licenseForm" path="/license"
            scope="request" parameter="action" type="fr.niji.struts.action.LicenseAction">

            <forward name="display" path="/displayLicense.jsp" />
            <forward name="add" path="/addLicense.jsp" />
        </action>

        <action attribute="equipmentsForm" name="equipmentsForm"
            path="/equipments" scope="request" parameter="action"
            type="fr.niji.struts.action.EquipmentsAction">

            <forward name="display" path="/displayEquipments.jsp" />
        </action>


        <!-- logout action -->
        <action attribute="logoutForm" input="/index.jsp" name="logoutForm"
            path="/logout" scope="request" type="fr.niji.struts.action.LogoutAction">
            <forward name="logout" path="/logoff.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

    <message-resources parameter="fr.niji.configuration.ApplicationResources"
        null="false" />
</struts-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of sweat, i find the solution. For modify the URL, i went on my jsp and modify the tag `html:form`.

For example with an action parameter "add":

`<html:form action="/platform.do?action=add" styleId="formPrincipale"> <html:hidden property="idPlatform" styleId="idPlatform"/> <html:hidden property="action" styleId="action" value="add"/>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Error 500 : javax.servlet.ServletException: Request[/platform] does not contain handler parameter named 'action'.

You are calling the action  mapped as `/platform` which requires a parameter named `action`. You should add a parameter `action` to the URL.

```xml
<action attribute="platformForm" name="platformForm" path="/platform"
        scope="request" parameter="action" type="fr.niji.struts.action.PlatformAction">

        <forward name="list" path="/listPlatforms.jsp" />
        <forward name="display" path="/displayPlatform.jsp" />
        <forward name="change" path="/displayPlatform.jsp" />
    </action>
```

Comment: Okay but why he need a parameter `action` when i wait 5 minutes and not in the other cases ?

Comment: Okay i understand better your answer, the problem is that the url pattern is defined on .do and i can't change the url 
`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`
I need to search who call platform.do.

Comment: The problem  is not related to servlet mapping. I don't know what happened after 5 min timeout (may be session), but you redirected to the action which expects a parameter but missing one cause the error.